# What is the difference between these two statements (asp.net/c#/entity framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
IEnumerable<Department> myQuery = (from D in myContext.Departments orderby D.DeptName select D);

var myQuery = (from D in myContext.Departments orderby D.DeptName select D);
```

What is the difference between these two statements above? In my little asp.net/C#/ EF4.0 app I can write them either way, and as far as how I want to use them, they both work, but there has to be a reason why I would choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(from D in myContext.Departments orderby D.DeptName select D);
```

returns an object of type `IQueriable<Department>` which in turn implements `IEnumerable<Department>`

while you use the `var` keyword in here the compiler replace it with `IQueriable<Department>`

Answer (score 2):

The second one is shorter (assuming type of `D` is `Department`).

(actually, the return type of the query may be something other than `IEnumerable`, like `IQueryable` but the point is, the type will be statically *inferred* from the right hand side of the assignment operator instead of being explicitly mentioned in code).

Answer (score 2):

[syntactic convenience](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I believe in the 2nd case the type of `myQuery` is an `IQueryable<Department>` rather than `IEnumerable`.  If you don't need anything specific to an IQueryable that you can't do with an IEnumerable then they behave the same.

The `var` keyword is just for convenience when the compiler can figure out the type without spelling it out. So instead of

`MyReallyLongGenericClassName<SomeOtherType> myObject = new MyReallyLongGenericClassName<SomeOtherType>();`

You can just write `var myObject = new MyReallyLongGenericClassName<SomeOtherType>();`

Answer (score 1):

With var the compiler infers the type of myQuery. It would probably endup being an `IQueryable<Department>` rather than an `IEnumerable<Department>`.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference here is that you're not declaring yourself the type of `myQuery`. You're taking advantage of a feature named [Type Inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb417257.aspx). Indeed the type returned will be `IQueryable<Department>` where the first statment explicitly types the variable as `IEnumerable`.